# In python ,How the method DocumentQuery() in gdata can use with image file such as .jpg .png?

Tags: python-2.7, google-docs-api, google-data-api

In Google Doc APIs with Python >> gdata.docs.service.DocumentQuery(categories)

1.)How can it use with the image files? or Do I set categoiries parameter ,or not?

2.)The parameter(categories) ,how many type of the categories? I'm just know only folder and document.

Thank You :)